# PHP retrieve records from database

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and web development in general. I wrote a simple PHP script based on my knowledge so far. Here it what it looks like, along with the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <title>Retrieve Users</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <body>
        <p> List of Subscribers </p>
        <?php
            $query = "select * from subscribers";
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","subscribers");
            $result;
            if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
                header("Location: unavailable.html");
                exit;
            }else{
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            }
        ?>
        <table>
            <?php 
                global $result;
                while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
                    $email = $row['email'];
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>"  $email  "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, I get this in my webpage :

```
List of Subscribers

"; echo ""; echo ""; } ?>
" $email "
```

**What changes do I need to make here?**

Comment: To concatenate a string you have to use the "." as so: echo "<td>".$email."</td>";

Comment: What's the extension of this file? Is it .html or .php ?

Comment: @RuslanBes `.html` :)

Comment: @RuslanBes Oh ! Dang !! -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting

```
"; echo ""; echo ""; } ?>
```

means PHP code wasn't parsed at all on this page. The most common reason for that is that this code is written in .html file and not .php.

By default PHP code in .html files is ignored.

The answer by @AbhikChakraborty makes sense too.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to concate

```
echo "<td>".$email."</td>";
```

**UPDATE**

The concate was not alone the issue, the file name was having wrong extension.

This kind of situation may happen in following cases

1. No PHP installed, in this it is most likely you may get php file getting downloaded intead of executing.
2. Wrong file extension
3. Using php short tag `<?` where in `php.ini` its not enable

Comment: I had tried that :( Didnt help. It just printed the dots

Comment: `"; echo ""; echo ""; } ?> ".$email."`

Comment: Then i must ask u is PHP installed and running ?

Comment: How dumb of me .. my file extension was wrong -_- it was `.html` instead of `.php`

Comment: Yes this kind of situation may happen in 3 cases 1. No PHP installed, 2. Wrong file extension 3. Using php short tag <? where in php.ini its not enabled.

Answer (score -1):

first, since you are on the same page, you don't need to global `$result`

second, it's better to use `mysqli` as a class, just for better practice

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <title>Retrieve Users</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <body>
            <p> List of Subscribers </p>
            <?php
                $query = "select * from subscribers";
    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "user" ,"pass" , "db_name" , null , null);
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","subscribers");
                var $result;
                if(!$con){
                    header("Location: /unavailable.html");
                    exit;
                }else{
                    $result = $con->query($query);
                }
            ?>
            <table>
                <?php 
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
                    while( $row  ){
                        $email = $row['email'];
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" .$email. "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
                    }
                ?>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: But there is nothing in your "answer" that solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, like I said, it's not an answer to the problem.

Comment: i just wanted to help him

Comment: That's not how this site works.  Only answers to the question get posted as answers.

Answer (score -2):

add a decimal before the "=" it will then display all

```
$email .= $row['email'];
```